# What is the difference between mAP from Mask R-CNN utils.py and mAP from (MS)COCO?

Tags: mask, metrics, faster-rcnn, mscoco, average-precision

I trained my Mask R-CNN Network with my own data, which i transformed into COCO Style for my Thesis and now i want to evaluate my results. I found two methods to do that. One method is the evaluation from COCO itself. Mask R-CNN itself shows how to evaluate with COCO Metric in their coco.py file:
https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN/blob/master/samples/coco/coco.py

I basically use the `evaluate_coco(...)` function in line 342. As a result i get the result from COCO metric with Average Precisions and Average Recall for different metrics, see the images below. For the parameter eval_type i use `eval_type="segm"`.

For me the mAP is interesting. I know that the mAP50 uses 0.5 for the IuO (Intersection over Union) and their standard mAP is from IuO = 0.5 until 0.95 in 0.05 steps.

The second method is from Mask R-CNN itself in their utils.py:
https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN/blob/master/mrcnn/utils.py

The name of the function is `compute_ap(...)` in line 715 and there is written that the IoU is 0.5. The function returns a mAP value.

This raises the question of what type `compute_ap()` evaluates for. With COCO you can choose between "bbox" and "segm".

Also i want to know the difference between the mAP value from the `compute_ap(...)` function and the mAP50 from COCO, because with the same data i get different results. 
Unfortunately i can't upload a better image now, because i can only go on Monday-Friday to my university and friday i was in a hurry and took pictures without checking them, but the mean Value over all AP from the `compute_ap()` is 0.91 and i am pretty sure that the AP50 from COCO is 0.81.

Do someone know the difference or is there no differnce?
[image: On Top the mAP over all APs from compute_ap() is 0,9108 and AP50 from COCO is 0.810]
[image: Here is the other COCO Metric result]

Is it because of the maxDets=100 Parameter?:
[Understanding COCO evaluation "maximum detections"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52839368/understanding-coco-evaluation-maximum-detections)
My pictures have only 4 categories and a maximum of 4 instances per picture.

Or is the way how the mAP is calculated different?

EDIT: Now i have a better image with the whole COCO Metric for Type "Segm" and Type "BBox" and compere it with the result from `compute_ap()`, which is "mAP: 0,41416..." By the way, if there is an "-1" in the COCO Result, does this mean there were no from this typ?

[image: COCO Metric and compute_ap() result comparison]